# create taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, themes, taxonomy

I am new to word press, I want to display results on a page which belong to some group from database(I have group column). I think this can be done by taxonomy so I have taxonomy table but I don't know what to write in taxonomy.php file, any idea what is the minimum information that I have to write in taxonomy.php to make it work.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What table is the group column in?  A custom table?  If so, taxonomies will have no relation to it whatsoever unless you define them at the database level.

Comment: @Andrew I want to display few rows from database which belong to some group on the front end of a page. I have 3 groups G1,G2 and G3 and three hyperlinks for these, when ever a user click G1 it goes to new page which shows all rows belong to group G1 and so on. I tried - baseUrl/my_taxonomy_name_from_table(wp_term_taxonomy)/G1 but it gives url not found and I have not configured or done any thing other then creating taxonomy page in them which just display posts.

Comment: Please delete this answer and reply to my comment, but as I asked, how are you storing these groups in the database?  See @elkirkmo's answer for how to register a taxonomy.

Comment: I am not able to see reply tag above after your ans. DB creation was done by some one else so I dont have much idea, there is one group column in my main data table which have G1.. G3 entries and there is one row for group in wp_term_taxonomy.

Comment: Just click "Add Comment".  Can you create the schema here please: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9af9b/2

Answer (score 0):

`Taxonomy.php` is the default template that displays how custom taxonomies display in the browser. They aren't how you create a new taxonomy. This is done by using the function `register_taxonomy()` in `functions.php`. Wordpress has created a whole codex page on the [topic available here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) SmashingMag has a [great tutorial on it as well](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/04/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/) (it's actually what I used to learn how to build custom taxonomies.

Hope this helps.